# Jquery working in aspx normal page but not in content page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-plugins

Both Code is same only difference is one is in master page and another is not.

I just want to know what change in code i need to do when we convert the page to master page in the jquery function calling and embedding

Here workign means I can see the css effects in page and Javascrpt validation get called 
This is not working (Content Page)

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="JqueryTest.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<%--<link rel="stylesheet" href='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("./JQuery/validationEngine.jquery.css")%>' type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("./JQuery/template.css")%>' type="text/css") />
<script src='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("./JQuery/jquery-1.6.min.js")%>' type="text/javascript">
    </script>
<script src='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("./JQuery/jquery.validationEngine-en.js")%>' type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8">
    </script>
<script src='<%=Page.ResolveUrl("./JQuery/jquery.validationEngine.js")%>' type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8">
    </script>--%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./JQuery/validationEngine.jquery.css"
    type="text/css"  />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./JQuery/template.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="./JQuery/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" >
    </script>
<script src="./JQuery/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8" >
    </script>
<script src="./JQuery/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"
    charset="utf-8" >
    </script>

    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
        });


        function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options) {
            if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
                // this allows to use i18 for the error msgs
                return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
            }
        }
    </script>


</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
  <p>
        <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
            onclick="alert(&#39;is the form valid? &#39;+jQuery(&#39;#formID&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;validate&#39;))">
            Evaluate form</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                onclick="jQuery(&#39;#sport&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;validate&#39;)">Validate
                sport1 select field</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                    onclick="jQuery(&#39;#sport&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;hide&#39;)">Close favorite
                    sport 1 prompt</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                        onclick="jQuery(&#39;#formID&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;hide&#39;)">Close all prompts
                        on form</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                            onclick="jQuery(&#39;#formID&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;updatePromptsPosition&#39;)">
                            Update all prompts positions</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                                onclick="jQuery(&#39;#test&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;showPrompt&#39;, &#39;This is an example&#39;, &#39;pass&#39;)">
                                Build a prompt on a div</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                                    onclick="jQuery(&#39;#test&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;hide&#39;)">Close div prompt</a>
        | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/index.html">Back
            to index</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        This demonstration shows the different validators available
        <br>
    </p>
    <div id="test" class="test" style="width: 150px;">
        This is a div element</div>
    <form id="formID" class="formular" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Required! </legend>
        <label>
            <span>Field is required : </span>
            <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="req" id="req">
        </label>
        <legend>Placeholder &amp; required </legend>
        <label>
            <span>Field is required : </span>
            <input value="This is a placeholder" data-validation-placeholder="This is a placeholder"
                class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="reqplaceholder" id="reqplaceholder">
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Favorite sport 1:</span>
            <select name="sport" id="sport" class="validate[required]">
                <option value="">Choose a sport</option>
                <option value="option1">Tennis</option>
                <option value="option2">Football</option>
                <option value="option3">Golf</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Favorite sport 2:</span>
            <select name="sport2" id="sport2" multiple="" class="validate[required]">
                <option value="">Choose a sport</option>
                <option value="option1">Tennis</option>
                <option value="option2">Football</option>
                <option value="option3">Golf</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <br>
        validate[required]
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Custom </legend>
        <label>
            <p>
                Comes with many predifined regex (phone, url, ip, email..etc)</p>
            <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoRegExp.html">
                [DEMO]</a>
            <br>
            <span>Enter a URL : </span>
            <input value="http://" class="validate[required,custom[url]] text-input" type="text"
                name="url" id="url">
            <br>
            validate[required,custom[url]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Function </legend>
        <label>
            <span>Write 'HELLO' : </span>
            <input value="" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input" type="text"
                id="lastname" name="lastname">
            <br>
            validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Past </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the value is a date in the past
            <br>
            <span>Please enter a date ealier than 2010/01/01</span>
            <input value="2009/06/30" class="validate[custom[date],past[2010/01/01]] text-input"
                type="text" name="past" id="past">
            <br>
            validate[custom[date],past[2010/01/01]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Future </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the value is a date in the future
            <br>
            <span>Please enter a date older than today's date</span>
            <input value="2011-01-" class="validate[custom[date],future[NOW]] text-input" type="text"
                name="future" id="future">
            <br>
            validate[custom[date],future[NOW]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Group required </legend>
        <label>
            Checks if at least one of the input is not empty.
            <br>
            <br>
            <span>Please enter a credit card</span>
        </label>
        <input value="" class="validate[groupRequired[payments]] text-input" type="text"
            name="creditcard1" id="creditcard1">
        <label>
            <strong>OR</strong></label><br>
        <label>
            Please enter a paypal acccount</label>
        <input value="" class="validate[groupRequired[payments],custom[email]] text-input"
            type="text" name="paypal" id="paypal">
        <label>
            <strong>OR</strong></label><br>
        <label>
            Please enter a bank account</label>
        <input value="" class="validate[groupRequired[payments],custom[integer]] text-input"
            type="text" name="bank" id="bank">
        <label>
            <strong>OR</strong></label><br>
        <label>
            Please choose from select</label>
        <select class="validate[groupRequired[payments]] text-input" type="text" name="bank2"
            id="bank2">
            <option value="">Choose a payment option</option>
            <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
            <option value="Bank">Bank account</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Date Range<br>
        </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the start date is before the end date Please enter an end date ealier
            than the start date<br>
            <br>
            <label for="date1">
                Start Date :
            </label>
            <input value="9/1/2009" class="validate[dateRange[grp1]]" type="text" id="date1">
        </label>
        <label>
            <label for="date2">
                End Date :
            </label>
            <input value="3/18/1985" class="validate[dateRange[grp1]]" type="text" id="date2">
            <br>
            validate[dateRange[grp1]]<br>
            Note* Both fields must have the same name
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Date Time Range<br>
        </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the start date and time are before the end date and time Please enter
            an end date ealier than the start date<br>
            <br>
            <label for="date1">
                Start Date Time:
            </label>
            <input value="9/1/2009 9:30:00 PM" class="validate[dateTimeRange[grp2]]" type="text"
                id="datetime1">
        </label>
        <label>
            <label for="date2">
                End Date Time:
            </label>
            <input value="9/1/2009 2:30:00 AM" class="validate[dateTimeRange[grp2]]" type="text"
                id="datetime2">
            <br>
            validate[dateTimeRange[grp2]<br>
            Note* Both fields must have the same name
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Credit Card </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the credit card number is at least theoretically valid, according the
            to the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm">Luhn checksum algorithm</a>,
            but not whether the specific card number is active with a bank, etc.
            <br>
            <br>
            Since credit cards are often presented in different formats, spaces and hyphens
            (' ','-') are simply ignored.
            <br>
            <br>
            Examples:<br>
            <ul>
                <li>4111 1111 1111 1111</li>
                <li>3737-321345-610004</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm">
                More examples</a>
            <br>
            <input value="" class="validate[required,creditCard] text-input" type="text" name="creditcard2"
                id="creditcard2">
            <br>
            validate[required,creditCard]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Checkbox </legend>
        <label>
            Check this <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoCheckBox.html">
                [DEMO]</a>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ajax </legend>
        <label>
            Check this <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoAjaxSubmitPHP.html">
                [DEMO]</a>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Validate &amp; Send the form!"><hr>
    </form>
</asp:Content>
```

This is working (Normal ASPX page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0081)http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html -->
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery Validation Engine</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./JQuery Validation Engine_files/validationEngine.jquery.css"
        type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./JQuery Validation Engine_files/template.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="./JQuery Validation Engine_files/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="./JQuery Validation Engine_files/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script src="./JQuery Validation Engine_files/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript"
        charset="utf-8">
    </script>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
        });


        function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options) {
            if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
                // this allows to use i18 for the error msgs
                return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
            onclick="alert(&#39;is the form valid? &#39;+jQuery(&#39;#formID&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;validate&#39;))">
            Evaluate form</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                onclick="jQuery(&#39;#sport&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;validate&#39;)">Validate
                sport1 select field</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                    onclick="jQuery(&#39;#sport&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;hide&#39;)">Close favorite
                    sport 1 prompt</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                        onclick="jQuery(&#39;#formID&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;hide&#39;)">Close all prompts
                        on form</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                            onclick="jQuery(&#39;#formID&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;updatePromptsPosition&#39;)">
                            Update all prompts positions</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                                onclick="jQuery(&#39;#test&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;showPrompt&#39;, &#39;This is an example&#39;, &#39;pass&#39;)">
                                Build a prompt on a div</a> | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html#"
                                    onclick="jQuery(&#39;#test&#39;).validationEngine(&#39;hide&#39;)">Close div prompt</a>
        | <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/index.html">Back
            to index</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        This demonstration shows the different validators available
        <br>
    </p>
    <div id="test" class="test" style="width: 150px;">
        This is a div element</div>
    <form id="formID" class="formular" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Required! </legend>
        <label>
            <span>Field is required : </span>
            <input value="" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="req" id="req">
        </label>
        <legend>Placeholder &amp; required </legend>
        <label>
            <span>Field is required : </span>
            <input value="This is a placeholder" data-validation-placeholder="This is a placeholder"
                class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="reqplaceholder" id="reqplaceholder">
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Favorite sport 1:</span>
            <select name="sport" id="sport" class="validate[required]">
                <option value="">Choose a sport</option>
                <option value="option1">Tennis</option>
                <option value="option2">Football</option>
                <option value="option3">Golf</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Favorite sport 2:</span>
            <select name="sport2" id="sport2" multiple="" class="validate[required]">
                <option value="">Choose a sport</option>
                <option value="option1">Tennis</option>
                <option value="option2">Football</option>
                <option value="option3">Golf</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <br>
        validate[required]
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Equals </legend>
        <label>
            <span>Password : </span>
            <input value="karnius" class="validate[required] text-input" type="password" name="password"
                id="password">
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>Confirm password : </span>
            <input value="kaniusBAD" class="validate[required,equals[password]] text-input" type="password"
                name="password2" id="password2">
            <br>
            validate[required,equals[password]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Function </legend>
        <label>
            <span>Write 'HELLO' : </span>
            <input value="" class="validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input" type="text"
                id="lastname" name="lastname">
            <br>
            validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MinSize </legend>
        <label>
            Minimum field size
            <br>
            <input value="" class="validate[required,minSize[6]] text-input" type="text" name="minsize"
                id="minsize">
            <br>
            validate[required,minSize[6]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>MaxSize </legend>
        <label>
            Maximum field size, optional
            <br>
            <input value="0123456789" class="validate[optional,maxSize[6]] text-input" type="text"
                name="maxsize" id="maxsize">
            <br>
            validate[maxSize[6]]<br>
            note that the field is optional - it won't fail if it has no value
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Min </legend>
        <label>
            integer &gt;= -5
            <br>
            <input value="-7" class="validate[required,custom[integer],min[-5]] text-input" type="text"
                name="min" id="min">
            <br>
            validate[required,custom[integer],min[-5]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Max </legend>
        <label>
            integer ,50]
            <br>
            <input value="55" class="validate[required,custom[integer],max[50]] text-input" type="text"
                name="max" id="max">
            <br>
            validate[required,custom[integer],max[50]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Past </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the value is a date in the past
            <br>
            <span>Please enter a date ealier than 2010/01/01</span>
            <input value="2009/06/30" class="validate[custom[date],past[2010/01/01]] text-input"
                type="text" name="past" id="past">
            <br>
            validate[custom[date],past[2010/01/01]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Future </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the value is a date in the future
            <br>
            <span>Please enter a date older than today's date</span>
            <input value="2011-01-" class="validate[custom[date],future[NOW]] text-input" type="text"
                name="future" id="future">
            <br>
            validate[custom[date],future[NOW]]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Group required </legend>
        <label>
            Checks if at least one of the input is not empty.
            <br>
            <br>
            <span>Please enter a credit card</span>
        </label>
        <input value="" class="validate[groupRequired[payments]] text-input" type="text"
            name="creditcard1" id="creditcard1">
        <label>
            <strong>OR</strong></label><br>
        <label>
            Please enter a paypal acccount</label>
        <input value="" class="validate[groupRequired[payments],custom[email]] text-input"
            type="text" name="paypal" id="paypal">
        <label>
            <strong>OR</strong></label><br>
        <label>
            Please enter a bank account</label>
        <input value="" class="validate[groupRequired[payments],custom[integer]] text-input"
            type="text" name="bank" id="bank">
        <label>
            <strong>OR</strong></label><br>
        <label>
            Please choose from select</label>
        <select class="validate[groupRequired[payments]] text-input" type="text" name="bank2"
            id="bank2">
            <option value="">Choose a payment option</option>
            <option value="Paypal">Paypal</option>
            <option value="Bank">Bank account</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Date Range<br>
        </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the start date is before the end date Please enter an end date ealier
            than the start date<br>
            <br>
            <label for="date1">
                Start Date :
            </label>
            <input value="9/1/2009" class="validate[dateRange[grp1]]" type="text" id="date1">
        </label>
        <label>
            <label for="date2">
                End Date :
            </label>
            <input value="3/18/1985" class="validate[dateRange[grp1]]" type="text" id="date2">
            <br>
            validate[dateRange[grp1]]<br>
            Note* Both fields must have the same name
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Date Time Range<br>
        </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the start date and time are before the end date and time Please enter
            an end date ealier than the start date<br>
            <br>
            <label for="date1">
                Start Date Time:
            </label>
            <input value="9/1/2009 9:30:00 PM" class="validate[dateTimeRange[grp2]]" type="text"
                id="datetime1">
        </label>
        <label>
            <label for="date2">
                End Date Time:
            </label>
            <input value="9/1/2009 2:30:00 AM" class="validate[dateTimeRange[grp2]]" type="text"
                id="datetime2">
            <br>
            validate[dateTimeRange[grp2]<br>
            Note* Both fields must have the same name
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Credit Card </legend>
        <label>
            Checks that the credit card number is at least theoretically valid, according the
            to the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm">Luhn checksum algorithm</a>,
            but not whether the specific card number is active with a bank, etc.
            <br>
            <br>
            Since credit cards are often presented in different formats, spaces and hyphens
            (' ','-') are simply ignored.
            <br>
            <br>
            Examples:<br>
            <ul>
                <li>4111 1111 1111 1111</li>
                <li>3737-321345-610004</li>
            </ul>
            <a href="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm">
                More examples</a>
            <br>
            <input value="" class="validate[required,creditCard] text-input" type="text" name="creditcard2"
                id="creditcard2">
            <br>
            validate[required,creditCard]
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Checkbox </legend>
        <label>
            Check this <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoCheckBox.html">
                [DEMO]</a>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Ajax </legend>
        <label>
            Check this <a href="http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoAjaxSubmitPHP.html">
                [DEMO]</a>
        </label>
    </fieldset>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Validate &amp; Send the form!"><hr>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check if `Jquery` JS files are downloaded to the client or not in content page.

Comment: @user1482424 - Depending on your browser you can use the developer tools. In IE 7+ you can hit `F12` to bring them up. In Chrome it's `Ctrl + Shift + I`. In FireFox it's `Ctrl + Shift + K`

Comment: I have developer tool now what i need to do?

Comment: @user1482424 - Check to see what the URL's of your scripts and styles are. Are they valid links that, when navigated to, return what you expect, or do you get "404 - NOT FOUND" errors. Did they actually load?

Comment: <script src="/WebResource.axd?d=MXy6fE2pCAGJAkUas9sgGwPwwn_dqO5U88MEumOMsPAgdyYLBh0K_4UDWzywwn3EeMJJP8_gVQawLQgHM_BAqBLoGsGSjoAgJAEmqOUDKcA1&t=634758712356603705" type="text/javascript"></script>I can see something like this :

Comment: but only one .axd .. this .axd should be for masterpage css and there no other .axd there so it shows css from pluggin is not loaded ?

Comment: Haha..its from webdeveloper i came to know that the control id is NOT formId it was ctl01  ... so its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another reason why I just use JQuery's or Google repository
Check this out: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/

Test using this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Or

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch without knowing your site structure, but `Page.ResolveUrl` is expecting a virtual path. You need to make your URL root relative.

```
Page.ResolveUrl("~/JQuery/jquery-1.6.min.js")
```

This will render the correct URL regardless of where your page is loaded from.

Comment: @user1482424 - You are going to have to show us what the actual errors are. Open up the developer tools in your browser and see what errors show up. Do the resources fail to load? Is there a script error? Your browser will give you all this information.

Comment: there is no error ..css is not getting loaded in the page when i use content page , and validation is not working take eg of date compare validations ..its not firing when i am on content page otherwise it is working